# Core Location not working when app is in background

Tags: ios, core-location

I am trying to make my app run Core Location in background without success.  I configured the correct key in `info.plist` and have the following code:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"background");

    MainViewController *view2 = [[MainViewController alloc]init];
    view2.localizacao.distanceFilter = 250;
    view2.localizacao.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    [view2.localizacao startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges]; 
}
```

When I run the app in foreground all works perfectly.  But in background, nothing.  What can I do?

Comment: Don't start monitoring significant changes.  That means it will only update if your location changes a lot.  Instead use `startUpdatingLocation` More info -> http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW1

Comment: Yes, i used that before but, how to make it runs from time to time to capture the location? I tried to use a timer but dont work on background too...

Comment: You can't...that is the same as running arbitrary code in the background.